# Using a batch file to pass a variable containing a the name to be used when creating the output text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a very simple batch file that reads a txt file and checks for the number "1", and creates a batch file with the results - very simple but works as expected.

@echo off

FIND /I "     1" "C:\PassFail.txt"  > C:\PassFailResult.txt

I want to name the output txt file using a variable:

e.g. FIND /I "     1" "C:\PassFail.txt"  > C:\"variablename".txt

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

The variable name will be a report id stored in another location so I would need to load the variable name into my batch file and then use this variable as the name of the output report.

I am running the script on a Windows server 2008 SP1, I'm also new to batch processing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ("the other file") do set OutputFile=%%a
find "1" "c:\passfail.txt" > "c:\%OutputFile%.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

> set variablename=C:/PassFailResult.txt

```
> FIND /l " 1" "C:/PassFail.txt" > %variablename%
```

Also see [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/630/using-variables-in-windows-batch-files/).